# Google BigQuery worked for me without billing until Yesterday. Was i just lucky so far?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have been using Google BigQuery without billing enabled until yesterday for the past 3 weeks (Until Jun 4th Australian Time). But today it gives me error stating "You have to enable Billing".

My Question is :

Was i just got lucky so far? Or something changed recently ?.

I started using Browser tool with public data then i created few tables and it all worked and then started using command line tool yesterday and today it gave me error.

Anybody faced similar issue ?

Comment: Just a reminder, Google BigQuery allows 100Gb per month of free query quota to all users, which can be used on public datasets for testing. After this (or if you ingest custom data, you'll need to make sure you have billing enabled on your projects).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google BigQuery is a premium service, and we started billing on June 1, 2012. We sent a reminder about this on our [bigquery-announce](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/bigquery-announce/cIXAxYIKCHs/discussion) mailing list (which is the list to subscribe to for announcements about new features) but here is the same information:

- The BigQuery API allows up to 100GB/mo of free query processing.
- After exceeding the free tier of query processing, your project must be signed up for billing. See our pricing page for more details. This is also required to be able to load data into the system.
- If you haven't activated billing on your project, and exceed the free quota, the BigQuery API will return a 403 "billingNotEnabled" error with the message: "Billing has not been enabled for this project."
- To enable billing on your project, you must register a credit card with Google Checkout.
- For more information, see this link for an overview of the Google API Console. Then see this page for steps to enable billing.
- Your first billing statement will arrive at the end of June, 2012.

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: Hi michael, 

Thanks for the information. i understand the same and looks like i have reached my free quota. The API console doesn't show how much of Free quota i have consumed.